# Silverlight 4 Application run in silverlight 5 in visual-studio-2015

Tags: silverlight-4.0, silverlight-5.0, toolkit

I have a silverlight application after i run this project in 
visual-studio-2015 silverlight 5  there errors are appear 
The tag 'TimeUpDown' does not exist in XML namespace

'http:// schemas.microsoft. com /winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/toolkit'

What can i do ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add a reference to `System.Windows.Controls.Input.Toolkit`.

See [this blog post](https://zoomicon.wordpress.com/2012/07/14/fix-the-tag-timeupdown-does-not-exist-in-xml-namespace-silverlight-toolkit/) for more details.